# filtering gallery based on SharePoint multi values column. and collection with multi values column

Tags: powerapps

I am facing an issue with filtering a gallery which has one column with multi values (SharePoint Multi Values column) called Team.

and I need to filter it based on another Colum which is also in Multi Values column inside collection.

I have tried the code below but none of it works

```
Filter(financetickets, 
Status.Value = VarStatus,
Left( Concat( Team,  Value & "," ), Len( Concat( Team,  Value & "," ) ) - 1 ) in
Left(Concat(ColTeamsRoles.FocalPoint,FocalPoint.Value&","),Len(Concat(ColTeamsRoles.FocalPoint,FocalPoint.Value&","))-1)
```

)

any suggestions, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the code to below to make it work and ignored the collection:

so, I just replaced the collection with a direct query

```
Filter(financetickets, 
Status.Value = VarStatus,
LookUp(Users,UserName.Email=User().Email,FocalPoint.Value) in Left( Concat( Team,  Value & "," ), Len( Concat( Team,  Value & "," ) ) - 1 )
```

)